# LINQ to TextFile in Windows Phone 7

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to read a text file using linq in wp7.  My requirement is i need to read the below given text file content and to form a list, How i can implement this in windows phone. The format of my text file is.

```
Game::Cricket::England::Pakistan  
Game::Football::England::France  
Game::Cricket::Pakistan::Australia
```

If Linq to Text file is not possible in wp7. Then suggest me a different alternative. The answer based on my text format is  highly appreciable

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following approach...

Create the class to hold your GameDetail object, and define a constructor that takes a string parameter.  This constructor can parse each individual line.

```
public class GameDetail
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Team1 { get; set; }
    public string Team2 { get; set; }

    public GameDetail(string input)
    {
        var parts = input.Split(new string[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if(parts.Length != 4) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input string");
        Type = parts[1];
        Team1 = parts[2];
        Team2 = parts[3];
    }
}
```

Create a reader method to read each line of the file, and add it to a collection of GameDetails

```
List<GameDetail>ReadFile(string filename)
{
    var stream = File.OpenRead(filename);
    var allData = new List<GameDetail>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while (( line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            allData.Add(new GameDetail(line));
        }
    }
    return allData;
}
```

**NOTE - Untested...**

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in support for Linq to Text in .NET (desktop, or phone). However, there is a rather fantastic Linq-to-CSV library no codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

This will almost certainly work on WP7. You can specify the delimiter, so it should work with your double-colon.

Comment: Is there any other method present to parse the text file.  Because of copyright issues presently i cant use any 3rd party libraries. Which is against our company rule .

Comment: Read it and parse it yourself! .. or just look at the source code for that project and create something rather similar ;-)

Comment: I'd post an answer, but then that would be a third-party source as well and would still have "copyright issues"

Answer (score 0):

you could always just load the file as text and split it on the "::"

```
using System.IO;

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();
foreach(string s in text.Split("\n"))
{
string[] splitstring = s.Split("::");
}
```